# How to map Hibernate entity where a primary key component and the foreign key have the same column name?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, many-to-one

I have problem with composite primary key and Foreign key having the same column name.

Example

Table A
PK (ID , NEW_ID)

Table B
PK (ID, NEW_ID)
FK (A_ID, NEW_ID)

I have the relationship of Entity B mapped to A in this way

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "NEW_ID", referencedColumnName = "NEW_ID")})
```

When I try to save B. I am getting an error of invalid Index.

So I am guessing it was also trying to set NEW_ID two times and getting this error.

I have no option to set one column as insertable and updatable as false.

Can any one help me in this

Answer (score 0):

One tip i can share is make the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create` and see what hibernate is doing , this will help you to debug , moreover make the `show_sql=true` , you will surely understand what this configuration will result into.

Please refer to http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html for details about annotation usage

Thanks
Abhi